# Client calling WebAPI stuck in await

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a httpclient that is calling a WebAPI service. The GET reaches the service and returns the content but the client just keeps waiting...

Client code:

```
    static async Task RunAsyncGet(string baseUri, string uri)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUri);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri); // <-- stuck here

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                IEnumerable<UserAccountModel> users = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<UserAccountModel>>();
                //...
            }
        }
    }
```

WebAPI code:

```
public class UserAccountController : ApiController
{
    private IRepository _repo;

    public UserAccountController(IRepository repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        var s = _repo.GetAllUserAccounts();

        IContentNegotiator negotiator = Configuration.Services.GetContentNegotiator();
        ContentNegotiationResult result = negotiator.Negotiate(typeof(AuthResponseModel), Request, Configuration.Formatters);

        var bestMatchFormatter = result.Formatter;
        var mediaType = result.MediaType.MediaType;

        return new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Content = new ObjectContent<IQueryable<UserAccount>>(s, bestMatchFormatter, mediaType)
        };
    }
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: It's possible that your `HttpClient` is getting disposed before it has a chance to resolve. I'd try it without the using wrapper.

Comment: I am using client.UploadData to get the results from web api

Comment: @TiesonT. - removed the wrapper, still no go. Gets stuck on the first await.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I ended up calling the WebAPI:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:23302");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/useraccount").Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var t = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<UserAccount>>().Result;
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        //Something has gone wrong, handle it here
    }
}
```

Comment: Solution shouldn't be around making whole call Synchronous.. Issue must be with caller code. Whoever is calling RunAsyncGet is not in async call

Answer (score 2):

Further up in your client code (whatever ends up calling `RunAsyncGet`), some code is calling `Task.Wait` or `Task<T>.Result`. That will [cause a deadlock if called from the UI thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), as I explain on my blog.

The proper solution is to change that `Wait`/`Result` to use `await`.

Comment: The task is being called from an MVC controller if that is any help?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, `RunAsyncGet` is on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your call to `EnsureSuccessStatusCode` is the likely culprit. That method actually returns a `HttpResponseMessage` that will have a HTTP status in the 200 range, or will throw an exception. So, you probably want something like:

```
static async Task RunAsyncGet(string baseUri, string uri)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();

    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUri);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

    IEnumerable<UserAccountModel> users = await response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode().Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<UserAccountModel>>();

    // ... the rest ...
}
```

Comment: No, it was never getting to that line. It was getting stuck on the line above that. I believe I solved it, without completely understanding why...

Comment: What were you passing in as baseUri and uri? The default API routing _does_ expect `/api/` as the first fragment after the domain.